# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error 139 (Webpack 5.11.1)

Tags: node.js, webpack, segmentation-fault, linux-mint

I've started creating a small educational project using Webpack:
https://github.com/Ray-Garraty/frontend-project-lvl3
When I try to make an initial build, I get the following error message:

```
    Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    npm ERR! code 139
    npm ERR! path /home/ray-garraty/Documents/frontend-project-lvl3
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command sh -c webpack
```

Here's the complete error log:

```
0 verbose cli [  
0 verbose cli   '/home/ray-garraty/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/bin/node',  
0 verbose cli   '/home/ray-garraty/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',  
0 verbose cli   'exec',  
0 verbose cli   '--',  
0 verbose cli   'webpack'  
0 verbose cli ]  
1 info using npm@7.3.0  
2 info using node@v15.5.0  
3 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms  
4 timing config:load:file:/home/ray-garraty/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules  /npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms  
5 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms  
6 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms  
7 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms  
8 timing config:load:file:/home/ray-garraty/Documents/frontend-project-lvl3/.npmrc Completed in 0ms  
9 timing config:load:project Completed in 0ms  
10 timing config:load:file:/home/ray-garraty/.npmrc Completed in 0ms  
11 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms  
12 timing config:load:file:/home/ray-garraty/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms  
13 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms  
14 timing config:load:cafile Completed in 1ms  
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms  
16 timing config:load:setUserAgent Completed in 0ms  
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms  
18 timing config:load Completed in 6ms  
19 verbose npm-session 7306a5ca90c48dfe  
20 timing npm:load Completed in 12ms  
21 timing command:exec Completed in 296ms  
22 verbose stack Error: command failed  
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ray-garraty/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)  
22 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:376:20)  
22 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1063:16)  
22 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:295:5)  
23 verbose pkgid @hexlet/code@1.0.0  
24 verbose cwd /home/ray-garraty/Documents/frontend-project-lvl3  
25 verbose Linux 5.4.0-58-generic  
26 verbose argv "/home/ray-garraty/.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/bin/node" "/home/ray-garraty  /.nvm/versions/node/v15.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "webpack"  
27 verbose node v15.5.0  
28 verbose npm  v7.3.0  
29 error code 139  
30 error path /home/ray-garraty/Documents/frontend-project-lvl3  
31 error command failed  
32 error command sh -c webpack  
33 verbose exit 139
```

Is there a problem with my Webpack config, or maybe smth else?
P.S.: I've tried reinstalling nvm, deleting and reinstalling the `node_modules` folder and rebuilding dependencies, tried to run it under different node.js versions, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem was caused by the wrong webpack config file extension:
it should be webpack.config.**cjs**, not webpack.config.**js**
Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/12308